# Testing a window event addEventListener with a callback using enzyme, mocha and chai

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, enzyme, chai

I am having trouble testing the callback in my window addEventListener that's wrapped in a useEffect. I am unable to get coverage for the callback `setHighRes` and also the

```
...  
return () => {
          window.removeEventListener("ATF_DONE", setHighRes);
        };
```

[image]
JSX file

```
  // Checks to see if image is cached
  const isCached = src => {
    const img = new Image(); // eslint-disable-line
    img.src = src;
    const complete = img.complete;
    img.src = "";
    return complete;
  };

  const [isHighRes, lazySetIsHighRes] = useState(
    !isCached(`${images[0].normal}?wid=200&hei=200`)
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    // If image is cached load the high res image after the ATF_DONE event
    if (!isHighRes) {
      const setHighRes = () => {
        lazySetIsHighRes(true);
        window.removeEventListener("ATF_DONE", setHighRes);
      };
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        window.addEventListener("ATF_DONE", setHighRes);
        return () => {
          window.removeEventListener("ATF_DONE", setHighRes);
        };
      }, ATF_TIMEOUT)
    }
    return null;
  }, []);
```

I tried doing this in the `spec.jsx` but it fails because expected addEventListener to have been called with arguments

```
    beforeEach(() => {
      sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
      sinon.stub(window, "addEventListener");
      sinon.stub(window, "removeEventListener");
      sandbox.stub(window, "Image").callsFake(() => {
        const image = new Image.wrappedMethod();
        sandbox.stub(image, "complete").value(complete);
        return image;
      });


    it.only("should load low res image if image is cached", () => {
      const clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
      clock.tick(8000);
        expect(window.addEventListener).to.have.been.calledWith("ATF_DONE", "setHighRes");
    })
```

Comment: Where does the `lazySetIsHighRes` come from, show the code

Comment: @slideshowp2 updated to show the code. It's to set state for `isHighRes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can manually dispatch the event to trigger the callback which worked for me

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event("ATF_DONE"));
```